# find and read lines in file then check comment lines

Tags: text-processing

i'm stuck with text file processing, here's what i'm trying to do.

i generated a git patch file using script, the patch file is big, and many changes are in the comments only, i split the big patch file into `my/patch/folder` using `splitdiff`, then i use `find` to inspect each split patch, to see if the change is in comments only. i created a separate shell script to check comments:

`comments.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

cat $file | grep ^+ | grep -v ^+++ | tr -d " " | tr -d "\t" | cut -c2-3 | while read -r line ; do
    if [ $line != "//" ] ; then
        exit 0
    fi
done

cat $file | grep ^- | grep -v ^--- | tr -d " " | tr -d "\t" | cut -c2-3 | while read -r line ; do
    if [ $line != "//" ] ; then
        exit 0
    fi
done

exit 1
```

i wanted to use this script to check if all changed lines are like this `+// this is comment`, so i know the changes are in comments only

then i ran below script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f small.patch
touch small.patch

find my/patch/folder -type f
-print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
for i
do
  ./comments.sh "$i"
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && cat "$i" >> small.patch
done
' _
```

but it seems the exit code from `./comments.sh "$i"` is always 1, i don't know why, i ended up creating the same big patch file

please help, thank you!

Comment: Do you use tab characters rather than spaces before comments?

Comment: @icarus, thanks for the reply, i added `tr -d "\t"`, result is the same

Comment: Please be aware that the while is run in a subshell and it's exit status is washed away and the final exit status is the last statement's status which is a 1 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some initial thoughts.

Using a `while read` loop is going to be slow compared to using say `grep -qv '//'`

`cat | grep | grep | TR | cut |grep` is going to be slow compared to just using `sed`.

Without having your actual data it is hard to tell what your problem is. So let us change the problem Figure out any easy to test alternative.

Obviously as I don't have your data I have not tested this.

So lets make a new noncomments.sh script. This one will return non comment lines.
This should be easy to test, run it over any patch file and see what non-comment lines it spits out.

```
#!/bin/sh
# delete the +++ and --- lines from unified diff. remove lines which are not
# added/removed. remove added/removed lines which are comments or blank
# output anything that is left
sed '/^+++/d;/^---/d;/^[+-]/!d;/^.[ \t]*\/\//d;/^.[ \t]*$/d' "$@"
```

and then tie them together

```
#!/bin/bash

find my/patch/folder -type f
-print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
for i
do
  [ -z "$(./noncomments.sh "$i")" ] || cat "$i"
done
' > small.patch
```

This only does the redirection once.

It would be possible to alternative the balance of the work  little more, for example make the script output nothing if the changes were just to comments and the whole file if there were none comment changes. Then the command would just be

`find my/patch/folder -type f -exec ./noncommentchanges {} \; > small.patch`

Comment: thank you, the first solution is close, it still contains some changes in comments

the second solution broke unified diff file, it only has `+` and `-` lines

Comment: btw, can i upload the patch file? i tried to edit my question and drag the file, it's not allowed

Comment: Put a sample patch file somewhere, e.g. pastebin.com, add the link here, I will take a look, and we can delete the comments.

Comment: I used splitdiff -a. For example cr.patch.part743.patch is a file with no non-comment changes. When I run this against the sed expression I get no output.

Comment: `find cr.patch.part74?.patch -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for i ; do [ -z "$(./cmd "$i")" ] || echo cat $i ;done'` shows it will cat 2 of the 4 files (741 and 742 will get outputted, 740 and 743 will not). Inspecting the files shows this to be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121260/discussion-between-icarus-and-jerry).

Answer (score 0):

Such scenarios are basically a.set of assertions we are making about the **git** diff data. And, whenever we hear assertions, we reach for **lookarounds**, e.g., they are in **Perl** regex engine.

```
find my/patch/folder -type f \
-exec perl -lne '
  tr/ \t//dr =~
  m{(?=^[-+])(?!^([-+])\1{2})(?=^.(?!//))}
    and exit 0}{exit 1
' {} \; -exec cat {} + > small.patch
```

---

Studying the regex:

```
# delete indiscriminately all spaces n TABs  
tr/ \t//dr =~
m{ (?# From where I stand...)
  (?=^[-+])   (?# I can see the beginning of line to my immediate eight followed by either a plus or minus sign)
    ### AND ###
  (?!([-+])\1{2}) (?# I donot see --- or +++ string at the beginning of line)
    ###:AND ###
  (?=.(?!//))  (# I donot see // as the 2nd and 3rd characters)
}x;
## so when all 3 assertions are met,
can we say that we have seen a 
noncomment commit line and so we 
promptly exit with a Unixy success (0)
 else we wait till the eof to exit with a 
Unixy failure (1)
```

Comment: thank you, i got a lot to learn